# How to compare only day, month, and year using timestamp?

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, python-datetime, python-dateutil

How do we can compare 2 dates if they have same date irrespective of timestamp?

For example:

```
date1 = 1508651293229
date2 = 1508651293220

date1 = datetime.fromtimestamp(int(date1) / 1e3)
date2 = datetime.fromtimestamp(int(date2) / 1e3)

if(date1 == date2):
  print(True)
```

but this checks for entire day stamp including time and I only want to check for day, month, and year.

I tried for some documentation but couldn't find much relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`datetime.datetime` instances have a `date` method that returns a `datetime.date` object, ignoring the time of the original value.

```
if date1.date() == date2.date():
```

You can also create the `datetime.date` instances directly if you don't care about the time, as `datetime.date.fromtimestamp` also exists.

```
date1 = datetime.date.fromtimestamp(date1 // 1000)
```

Comment: It works but it checks for date as well as time but I only want day, month and year portion of it

Comment: Then you misstated your intent in the question: "I only want to check for day, month, and year.
"

Comment: My Bad, corrected. Any Idea how to avoid time portion from that

Comment: This does. The `date` object returned by the `date` method doesn't include the time. `datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(date1//1000).date()` and `datetime.date.fromtimestamp(date1//1000)` both return `datetime.date(2017, 10, 22)`

Comment: If you *really* only care about the day, each `datetime.date` instance has a `day` attribute, e.g., `datetime.date.fromtimestamp(date1//1000).day == 22`

Comment: The first comment is simply not true: `.date()` discards time completely. It really returns just the YMD portion, i.e. the `datetime` truncated down to midnight. I don't understand the forth and back above.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
if date1.date() == date2.date():
    print('True')

# and indeed, they are:
True
```

Comment: It works but it checks for date as well as time but I only want day portion of it

Comment: no, it doesn't check for time. `.date()` returns just the date (year, month, day) part of the `datetime`.

Answer (score 1):

> `datetime.date()` returns a date object with the same year, month, and day

In your case, you should use:

```py
if(date1.date() == date2.date()):
  print(True)
```

You can also shorten this by simply doing

```
print(date1.date() == date2.date())
```

Comment: It works but it checks for date as well as time but I only want day portion of it.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "day portion of it?" `date1.date()` and `date2.date()` both equal `2017-10-22`. If you want just the day of the month (ignoring month and year) you can use `date1.day` which would be `22`.

Comment: I recommend checking out the [datetime documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime). It may solve your problem.